# Applying styles to Header in p:datatable

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I would like to know how to apply the styles for the header column in the primefaces Datatable. I was able to change the styles for the rows using the rowStyleClass attribute. But not sure, how to change the style for the header columns. A sample example would be really helpful. I have tried the below, but the style for the entire column seems to get changed

```
 <p:column id="SelectallID" headerText="Select ID" style="text-align:center; background-color:#C6C3C6;padding:12px;">
 <h:outputText>
 <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkbox2"  value="#{car.selected}"/>
 </h:outputText>
 </p:column>
```

when I use the above, the entire column style seems to get changed. But I want to change the style for only the header columns. Please Assist. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: "header columns"? Don't you mean "column headers"?

Comment: Hi BalusC thanks for the response.  Yes I meant the column Headers

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Primefaces datatable headers generate a html `<th>` element. You could use an element selector in your style definition:

```
th {
  color: red !important;
}
```

This will for instance change the font color of all `<th>` elements on the page.

If this selection is not specific enough for your purposes, you can combine it with the id of the datatable:

```
#review-table th {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.As specified I have included the below style in my code. But the styles are not being applied to the header. where review-table is the id of the p:datatable.

    .review-table th{
   text-align:center;
   background-color:#85C2FF;
   border-bottom:1px solid;
   padding:12px;
   }

Your help on this is much Appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The id selector starts with `#` and not with a dot. Updated my answer.

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks for the response. I changed the id selector with # but still the styles were not applied to the header :(. Not sure if Im doing anything wrong

Comment: Check the source code in browser for the correct id. Maybe you have a NamingContainer around it, then the id would be something like someID:review-table. CSS needs the full id to identify the correct component. (or you need a different selector). Note that the colon `:` needs to be escaped by a backslash, e.g. `someID\:review-table`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response Matt.I was able to apply styles to the header,by specifing the name of the naming container as well. #form\:review-table.mystyle th{
   text-align:center;
   background-color:#9CD7F7;
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: inherit;
   }                                                                The style was applied only to the headerText alone not the entire column. Not sure why. I tried to debug using chrome and it takes the default style class 'ui-state-default' for role="columnheader". Once I tried changing the style class in the browser

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but just in case someone else finds it:

You can create a p:dataTable with a p:columnGroup like this:

```
<p:dataTable id="example" value="#{bean.values}" var="value">
    <p:columnGroup type="header">
      <p:column headerText="column1" />
      <p:column headerText="column2" styleClass="text-left"/>
      <p:column headerText="column3" styleClass="text-left"/>
    </p:columnGroup>
    <p:column>#{value.val1}</p:column>
    <p:column>#{value.val2}</p:column>
    <p:column>#{value.val3}</p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

The style in the columnGroup will affect the headers `<th>` and the style in the rest of the columns will affect the `<td>`

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can target the table header of all `<p:dataTable>` with the following code:

```
.ui-datatable thead th {
    background-image: none !important;
    background-color: var(--primary-color) !important;
    color: var(--secondary-color) !important;
}
```

You may need to use `!important` to override inherited properties

**EDIT:** I agree with @Kukeltje's comment about avoiding the usage of `!important`, which results in the logic used by the accepted answer.

```
.reskinned-datatable th {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
    color: var(--secondary-color);
}
```

Comment: _"You may need to use !important to override inherited properties"_ Better to use a more specific selector by e.g. adding an explicit class to the datatable. !important should be prevented as much as possible