# How do i change the background-color of my dataTable header in Java using JSF Framework?

Tags: css, primefaces

I'm using JSF 2.1 with Primefaces 4.0 on Glassfish 3.2.1.

In my *default.css* file, I have this code:

```
.facetHeaderUM .ui-datatable-header {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    border: none !important;
}
```

Below is the code Im using in my xhtml file.

```
<p:dataTable id="items" var="item" value="#{EmailRcpts.listsofEmail}" 
      style="width:400px; text-align:left; font-size:12px;" 
      styleClass="facetHeaderUM"
      widgetVar="itemWidVar"
      paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom"
      paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}" 
      currentPageReportTemplate="{totalRecords} record(s) in {totalPages} page(s)"
      rows="10">

      <f:facet name="header">
          <p:outputPanel style="font-style: italic; font-weight: bold; " >
              <p:inputText id="globalFilter" style="width:150px;margin-left: -53%" 
                  value="#{EmailRcpts.search}" /> &#160;
              <p:commandButton id="filterBtn" icon="ui-icon-search" 
                  style="font-style: italic;"/>
              <p/>
          </p:outputPanel>
      </f:facet>
```

In my p:dataTable I'm using `styleClass=facetHeaderUM`. I want to achieve transparent background-color and border-color in my dataTable header.

Using facetHeaderUm styleClass doesn't work. Default background-color of my p:dataTable header which is red still reigns.

Default.css file is attached correctly. It has many attributes and its working except to the  attribute I have written above.

Comment: You'll increase your audience dramatically if you just copy the generated HTML. Please check if your stylesheet is actually applied. Your browser's developer view should be able to tell you if the class applies to your header at all and if it is applied, what's more important than your definition.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796203/applying-styles-to-header-in-pdatatable

Comment: Hi Sir Blue Ocean, I tried the link you have sent but nothing happens. Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the primefaces theme you are using, I've found you also have to override the `background-image` property.

```
.facetHeaderUM .ui-datatable-header {     
    background-color: transparent !important;     
    border: none !important;

    background-image: none !important; 
}
```